# WKHTMLTOPDF in Laravel 4.1 PHP5.5 Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, shell, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I have implemented wkhtml2pdf through the package laravel-pdf (https://packagist.org/packages/ignited/laravel-pdf) which makes use of a slim wrapper around wkhtmltopdf written by Michael Haertl (https://packagist.org/packages/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

It used to work fine. Then I upgraded to PHP5.5 and Laravel 4.1.

Now I get the following error:

```
Could not run command '' --bin '/var/www/docassembly/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64' /tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_f0LNZv.html /tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_gJY5R6: sh: 1: : Permission denied
```

It looks like Apache doesn't have the permissions to execute the binary.
The binaries are owned by the apache user and are 777. It does write an empty file to the tmp directory though. The /tmp folder is also 777 and owned by apache user.

When I run the command manually in the terminal, it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: hey, were you able to solve this?... i can't seem to find any solutions online either...

Comment: I think they changed 'bin' to 'binPath' in the config ... (I have dropped this for another one)

Comment: actually i found this: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf and it took care of everything for me. also, whoever uses this library just don't forget the preceeding "./" before your bin path when on a Linux

Answer (score -2):

First check what is the file permission with command 
`ls -l /var/www/docassembly/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`.

Should be 
`-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data 38824584 Aug 17 00:40 wkhtmltopdf-amd64`.

If not change with command
`chmod 700 /var/www/docassembly/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP stated that he already checked for permission issues and everyone has execute privileges.